# Streams : how map in Streams work

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

To understand the `map` function in Streams better I was trying something like this:

```
String inputString="1+3+5";
Stream.of(inputString.split("\\+")).map(
    eachStringLiteral -> {
        output += mapOfStringAndNumber.get(eachStringLiteral) + literal;
    }
);
```

Where **`inputString`** is:

```
String inputString = "1+3+5";
```

however, the compiler complains and I don't know why:

> The method map(Function) in the type
>   Stream is not applicable for the arguments ((
>   eachStringLiteral) -> {})

I also need some help in order to understand the syntax in

`Function<? super String,? extends R>`.

**Update**

This is whole code illustrating what I am trying to achieve:

```
HashMap<String,Double> mapOfStringAndNumber=new HashMap<String,Double>();

        mapOfStringAndNumber.put("1",270.5);
        mapOfStringAndNumber.put("2",377.5);
        mapOfStringAndNumber.put("3",377.5);
        String inputString="1+3+5";
        String literal="+";
       String output;
      java.util.stream.Stream.of(inputString.split("+")).map(eachStringLiteral->
      output+=mapOfStringAndNumber.get(eachStringLiteral)+literal
```

Comment: please show us how you declared `mapOfStringAndNumber`, `count` and `literal`

Comment: for `map` you need to supply a function like `Function<? super String,? extends R>`, which takes a String or any super type of String as input and returns a type `R` which is then the element type of the new stream the `map` returns.

Comment: What is your desired output? Is it `"270.5+377.5+"`?

Comment: @slartidan yes.

Comment: The `Function<? super String,? extends R>` signature is explained in [What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you provide a `Double` value to each input `String` in your map `mapOfStringAndNumber`, you could use [`Pattern#splitAsStream(CharSequence input)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) to split your input `String` directly as a `Stream` and use [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) to build your `output` with `+` as delimiter, so your final code could be:

```
Map<String,Double> mapOfStringAndNumber = new HashMap<>();
mapOfStringAndNumber.put("1",270.5);
mapOfStringAndNumber.put("3",377.5);
mapOfStringAndNumber.put("5",377.5);
String inputString = "1+3+5";
String output = Pattern.compile("\\+")
    .splitAsStream(inputString)
    .map(mapOfStringAndNumber::get)
    .map(d -> Double.toString(d))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("+"));

System.out.println(output);
```

**Output:**

```
270.5+377.5+377.5
```

Comment: `Stream.of(inputString.split("\\+")).forEach(
    eachStringLiteral -> {
        output += mapOfStringAndNumber.get(eachStringLiteral) + literal;
    }
);` won't work, because variables used in lambda expressions should be final or effectively final.

Comment: @Shem you assume that they are **local** variables which is not true here otherwise the OP would have this compilation error too

Comment: @NicolasFilotto thanks for your post , its helpful +1 . but as Shem mentioned after removing the {} i have this "local variable must be final" .I know what this error means but i am not sure how can i have the intermediate results.

Comment: If it is local after all, you cannot modify it inside a lambda. See my answer on how to do this  fully functional.

Answer (score 2):

`map`, by definition, takes an input stream and applies a `Function` to each element of this stream, creating a new stream out of those modified elements.

So the count of items in input stream **has** to be the same as the count of items in output stream.

The error you are mentioning occurs, because your mapping function does not return anything: `output+=mapOfStringAndNumber.get(eachStringLiteral)+literal` only modifies the `output` variable and returns nothing.

From what I'm seeing here, you want to perform `map` and `reduce` operations:

- `map` operation changes each element of input stream into its value from `mapOfStringAndNumber` and adding `literal` to it
- `reduce` operation, in your case, is summing up all elements of your stream

To achieve this using Java 8 features, you need to first `map` the elements of your stream and then sum them up. You can do it like this:

```
String sum = Stream.of(inputString.split("\\+"))
       .map(stringLiteral->
          mapOfStringAndNumber.get(stringLiteral).toString())
       //join all the strings in the stream with a provided delimiter
       .collect(Collectors.joining(literal));
```

Comment: Quite helpful post +1 for that but i have to get the intermediate results as well.

Comment: @Roxy see my edit. I think now it does what you wanted (rewrites the equation with swapped variables)

Comment: Why mapToDouble, cant i use simple Map?

Comment: Yep, I put it there by mistake. Edit: see the code now. You also need to escape the "+" in split regex.

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of suggestions for your code:

1. If you use a `{}`-block and you want to create a `Function` (not a `Runnable`, `Consumer` or similar) you have to **`return`** something.
2. Unless you have a very special case, use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) instead of a Map of Strings to Integers
3. You must not modify `output` from within a Stream. That could lead to concurrancy issues.
4. Do you really need `literal`?

My example code for your usecase would look like this:

```
String inputString="1+3+5";
return

        // split input and create stream
        Stream.of(inputString.split("\\+"))

        // convert each item to Integer
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)

        // sum up everything
        .sum();
```

Comment: Your post is helpful so  +1 , but regarding point 3  how will i get the output ?

Comment: @Roxy the sum of the output is returned by the code. Do you also need the intermediate results?

Comment: Yieh, i am updating my post so please see what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`output+=mapOfStringAndNumber.get(eachStringLiteral)+literal;` is an expression. Lambda expressions that have a body consisting of a single expression should not have them placed within curly braces:

```
Stream.of(inputString.split("+")).map(eachStringLiteral -> 
  output+=mapOfStringAndNumber.get(eachStringLiteral)+literal;
);
```

See the section of the Java Language Specification concerning [lambda bodies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2):

> A lambda body is either a single expression or a block (§14.2)...
>
> ```
> LambdaBody:
> ```
>
> > ```
> > Expression
> > Block
> > ```

Alternatively you can just add a `return` clause before the `output` variable to make it a statement.